# gzip decompression using zlib library

Tags: c, gzip, zlib, compression

I have a problem with decompressing some gzip data. I have an array with pointers to dynamically allocated char strings. Each element of this array is one part of the gzip file that I want to uncompress. 
The first thing which comes to my mind is to concatenate those strings to one, and then decompress data, but I want to avoid this method because of a lot of copying.

So the question is: Is there any way to decompress data divided into few parts, using zlib library ? I was trying to do it, but when I decompress the first part I get Z_DATA_ERROR - and it's normal, because the data is not complete. Is there any way to "wait" for the rest of data to decompress?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://hewgill.com/journal/entries/349-how-to-decompress-gzip-stream-with-zlib  You should be able to call `inflate()` multiple times with the chunks to decompress one by one....

Comment: yes, I don't have a problem to decompress gzip file when it is in one piece. I am only wondering what to do when I have it in few parts. I wanted to do it one by one, but when I am decompressing the first part I am getting Z_DATA_ERROR because it is not complete, hence it is not decompressed

Comment: Check the [advanced functions in the reference](http://www.zlib.net/manual.html#Advanced), there you will find the `inflateBack` function which uses callbacks to read and write data.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You can simply call `inflate()` successively with each of the strings in the appropriate order.  for each call of `inflate()`, you can provide a different pointer and length for the compressed data. Each time, make sure that you first consume all of the uncompressed data generated and that `avail_in` is zero before moving on to the next chunk of input.

If you are getting a `Z_DATA_ERROR` that means that either you are not reassembling the original stream correctly, or that the original stream is not a gzip stream.

Note that to decompress a gzip stream, you need to initialize with `inflateInit2()` and set the parameters appropriately to request gzip decompression.